# Swift: Run two SKActions at the same time

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, operating-system, swift5

I want to run two SKActions at the same time:

`SKAction.move`  and
`SKAction.fadeAlpha`.

I've already found solutions in Objective-C, but I'm looking for solutions in Swift.

Currently I'm using `SKAction.sequence ([SKAction.move (to: event.location (in: self), duration: 3), SKAction.fadeAlpha (to: 0, duration: 1)])` but I want to that both SKActions **are executed at the same time** and **not consecutively**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `SKAction.group` to run several actions at the same time.

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417688-group